# Can’t update Dash DataTable using Pandas DataFrame.to_dict(‘records’)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am trying to update a DataTable with content from an xlsx table the user uploads like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('user-input-table', 'data'),
    Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
    State('upload-data', 'filename'))
def table_upload(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
        decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        try:
            if 'xls' in filename:
                df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded),skiprows=2,engine='openpyxl')
                return df.to_dict('records')
        except:
            print('There was an error')
```

Unfortunately this is not working, but instead returns the following error:

> dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for  returned a value having type list which is not
> JSON serializable.
>
> The value in question is either the only value returned, or is in the
> top level of the returned list,
>
> and has string representation [{'Quantity': 'Exhaust mass flow',
> 'Unit': 'kg/h', 100: 11881.0, 85: 0, 75: 10879.0, 50: 8476.0, 25:
> 5774.0, 10: 4810.0}, {'Quantity': 'T after turbine', 'Unit': '°C', 100: 444.0, 85: 0, 75: 383.0, 50: 332.0, 25: 320.0, 10: 320.0},
> {'Quantity': 'Engine speed', 'Unit': 'rpm', 100: 1800.0, 85: 0, 75:
> 1800.0, 50: 1800.0, 25: 1800.0, 10: 1800.0}, {'Quantity': 'Wastegate position', 'Unit': '%', 100: 0.0, 85: 0, 75: 0.0, 50: 0.0, 25: 0.0,
> 10: 0.0}, {'Quantity': 'Nox raw spec.', 'Unit': 'g/kWh', 100: 8.74,
> 85: 0, 75: 7.23, 50: 9.6, 25: 11.4, 10: 15.9}, {'Quantity': 'Nox req.
> spec.', 'Unit': 'g/kWh', 100: 1.4, 85: 0, 75: 1.4, 50: 1.4, 25: 1.4,
> 10: 1.4}, {'Quantity': 'Nox NTE', 'Unit': 'g/kWh', 100: 2.4, 85: 0,
> 75: 2.4, 50: 2.4, 25: 2.4, 10: 2.4}]

The string representation in the error message actually looks fine to me. From what I gathered online, the data input for a DataTable should be a list of dictioniaries with the column names as entries. This is exactly what I am providing here I would think.

Why does Dash say that my input is not JSON serializable?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update the DataTable `columns` as well :

```
@app.callback(
    Output('user-input-table', 'data'),
    Output('user-input-table', 'columns'),
    Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
    State('upload-data', 'filename'))
def table_upload(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
        decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
        try:
            if 'xls' in filename:
                df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded),skiprows=2,engine='openpyxl')
                data = df.to_dict('records')
                columns = [{"name": str(i), "id": str(i)} for i in df.columns]
                return data, columns
        except:
            print('There was an error')
```